# Did Adolf Hitler really snub Jesse Owens at the 1936 Olympics in Berlin?

Tags: history, olympics, track-and-field

Did Jesse Owens want to shake Hitler's hand and get their photo together and, if so, did Hitler really snub him?

I'm asking this based on a movie I'm watching.

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether sports.SE or skeptics.SE is a better site for this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Jesse Owens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Owens) was snubbed by who?

> Everyone knows that at the 1936 Olympics Hitler snubbed Jesse Owens. As the story goes, after Owens won one gold medal, Hitler, incensed, stormed out of Olympic Stadium so he wouldn't have to congratulate Owens on his victory.
>
> The facts are simple. Hitler did not congratulate Owens, but that day he didn't congratulate anybody else either, not even the German winners. As a matter of fact, Hitler didn't congratulate anyone after the first day of the competition. That first day he had shaken hands with all the German victors, but that had gotten him in trouble with the members of the Olympic Committee. They told him that to maintain Olympic neutrality, he would have to congratulate everyone or no one. Hitler chose to honor no one.
>
> **Hitler did snub a black American athlete, but it was Cornelius Johnson, not Jesse Owens.** It happened the first day of the meet. Just before Johnson was to be decorated, Hitler left the stadium. A Nazi spokesman explained that Hitler's exit had been pre-scheduled, but no one believes that. - [Adolf Hitler, Jesse Owens and the Olympics Myth of 1936.](http://historynewsnetwork.org/article/571)

Hitler seems to have snubbed both men, but Cornelius Johnson was snubbed first.

Upon his return to the USA, Jesse Owens had this to say:

> "When I came back to my native country, after all the stories about Hitler, I couldn't ride in the front of the bus," Owens told ESPN. "I had to go to the back door. I couldn't live where I wanted. I wasn't invited to shake hands with Hitler, but I wasn't invited to the White House to shake hands with the president, either." - [Did Hitler Really Snub Jesse Owens at 1936 Berlin Olympics?](http://www.bet.com/news/global/2013/08/03/did-hitler-really-snub-jesse-owens-at-1936-berlin-olympics.html)

Jesse Owens deserved better!

For those interested, here is a YouTube documentary on it: 
[Jesse Owens at the Berlin Olympics in 1936](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1inifMJ0xio).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer but it's a little confusing. The first paragraph and the last block quote seem to answer "yes this is true" but the bold line seems to say "no this is false"...? Unless Owens was lying in the last quote I take it that this is true, but if you could provide clarification I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The way I would understand  it is that Hitler snubbed both men, but Cornelius Johnson was snubbed first.

Comment: As far as I know Hitler do no it congratulates personally with athlete who were not German. Some [papers](https://news.google.co.uk/newspapers?id=zsoaAAAAIBAJ&sjid=IkwEAAAAIBAJ&pg=1814,6536771&dq=jesse-owens+hitler&hl=en) shows also that Owens and Hitler greeted each other

Comment: "Hitler seems to have snubbed both men" I don't think that is supported by your quotes. Whether or not Hitler snubbed Johnson depends on what exactly you think that "snubbed" means and whether "I'm only going to shake hands with Germans" counts a snub to any specific non-German person. But I don't think "Fine, I won't shake _anybody's_ hand" can be seen as a snub to Owens. Germany only won 23% of the medals at the games so, even on that first day, Hitler presumably didn't shake a lot of hands.

Comment: I have to say that part of the confusion for me (which I still don't get) is why Jesse and any other AA athlete would *want* to or would be willing to shake hands with Adolf Hitler. I suppose you could say they didn't know he was the embodiment of evil, but if there's any truth to the movie "Race" then the NAACP, press, and tons of other people actually did make that extremely clear to Jesse beforehand and asked him not to go to the Olympics in protest of it. I can understand why he went anyway, but I can't understand wanting to buddy up with Hitler.

Comment: @Hack-R: I can think of several things. An athlete would usually feel proud of being congratulated by the highest authority of the country. And, by 1936, Hitler was not remarkable in his racism and the concentration camps did not exist. While Hitler was extremely racist and his "cleansing" was a crime of the highest caliber, he was not that far away from many leaders of the time, and I'm not sure he would appear first in a rational ranking of "evil leaders". Finally, racism was par of the course back then, in many places and in particular in the US.

Answer (score 7):

Owens, a lifelong member of the Republican party, said

> "Hitler didn't snub me - it was [FDR] who snubbed me. The president
>   didn't even send me a telegram,"

at a Republican rally in October, 1936. You could say he was not snubbed based on his own words, though I think his words may have been a little politically motivated and not representative of his thoughts.

Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Owens), a journalist named Siegfried Mischner claims that Owens showed him a picture of Owens and Hitler shaking hands hoping the journalist would "change the accepted version of history" of that day. This, however, is very unlikely given no photo has ever surfaced and that it contradicts some of Owens's own statements.

Comment: [This photograph has yet to surface, and Owens — who died in 1980 — has never confirmed this story.](http://www.bet.com/news/global/2013/08/03/did-hitler-really-snub-jesse-owens-at-1936-berlin-olympics.html)

Comment: Ethan is correct that Wiki does make this reference, but it's saying that it's something being claimed by Siegfried Mischner, a German journalist, and to Ken's point it seems extremely unlikely. If that were actually true there'd be some copy of this photo on the Internet and it would conflict with the quotes that we know come directly from Owens. I would blame Wiki's quality issues for this, but I believe a German journalist may have claimed something like that, given that he was in a position to hear rumors and it was before the Internet made the world smaller and more verifiable.

Comment: @Hack-R I have corrected my answer to say that the journalist only claimed. Thank You

Comment: Thanks. So, Jesse Owens was a Republican? Update - you're right, I confirmed it from 3 sources. Apparently Owens was a staunch Republican to the very end.

Comment: @Hack-R Yes, but bear in mind, I think the republican party of his day was a bit different in its political views than it was today. Somewhere along the line, the republican and democratic party switched political sides, and I think it was happening during his time period, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @EthanGodden You're right, it was the Republicans who sought to end slavery and the Dems who defended it, and they later switched constituencies but I mean Owens and Ronald Reagan apparently attended the same Republican events at the same time. Owens came after the switch.

Comment: @EthanGodden - Wow - no.  They did not "switch" in the 20th century.  The Republican and Democratic parties are the exact same today as Jesse's time.  They did "change" going back a couple hundred + years ago.  A little information in the wrong hands can be dangerous.

Comment: Owens himself somewhat contradicted that German journalist.. " I wasn't invited to shake hands with Hitler, but I wasn't invited to the White House to shake hands with the president, either"    Yet that german journalist claims  he shook hands with Hitler.   So Owens  clearly means that he didn't shake hands with either hitler or the president.. That totally contradicts the german journalist's claim that Owens shook hands with Hitler

Comment: Also Hitler was reported to have said "'The Americans ought to be ashamed of themselves for letting their medals be won by negroes. I myself would never shake hands with one of them.'" So the german journalist, speaking over 70 years after the event, and after owens and hitler's death,  is contradicting both owens and hitler..